# can MediaExtractor used to extract content from .m4s or .ts file?

Tags: android, media-player

I'm trying to build a mepg-dash media player, the media segment to play is either .m4s or .ts file. What I trying to do is to use MediaExtractor for extracting media data. However, when I pass the file descriptor to setDataSource(), an IOException is thrown saying "Failed to instantiate extractor."

So my question is, can MediaExtractor work with .m4s or .ts file? If not, is there any other way of doing this?